# Django how to delete sender from list

Tags: python, django

I am using django signals for create an notifications system.I want to delete sender from list if his status sender and receiver same. Let you explain Mr. Jhone send an message to all users and Mr Jhone aslo included in all user group. So I want to remove Mr. Jhone from list of all user. Here I tried this code but didn't work:

```
 if sender in notifications: #here I am trying to remove sender from notifications list
                notifications.remove(Notifications(sender=sender, receiver= receiver,text_preview=text,notification_type="global_noti"))
```

here is my full code:

```
  def global_noti(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
          global_notify = instance
          sender =global_notify.user
          receivers = User.objects.all()
          text = global_notify.text
          if global_notify.is_published == 'global_notification':
            notifications=[]
            for  receiver in receivers:
                    notifications.append(Notifications(sender=sender, receiver= receiver,text_preview=text,notification_type="global_noti"))
            if sender in notifications: #here I am trying to remove sender from notifications list
                notifications.remove(Notifications(sender=sender, receiver= receiver,text_preview=text,notification_type="global_noti"))
            Notifications.objects.bulk_create(notifications)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense to me.  You're adding notifications for a bunch of recipients for one sender.  That is, EVERY notification in that list is going to be for that one sender.  Right?  `if sender in notifications:` will never be true, because the list contains `Notifications` objects, and `sender` is not one.

Comment: @Tim Roberts so couldn't remove the sender?? right???

Comment: @Tim Roberts I just want to remove the objects where sender and receiver are same person

Comment: Then shouldn't you just put `if sender != receiver:` in your `for` loop?

Comment: Tim Roberts no didn't put...thanks for the recommendation